# Delete a folder in Git that does not appear locally

Tags: git

I have a strange problem where I am trying to delete a directory that appears in Git called `test_directory`. However, it does not appear locally as I deleted it manually. 
Hence, this command `git rm -r --cached test_directory` will not work as it 'does not match any files'. any solutions to this?

Comment: Just try with `git rm text_directory` and do test_directory has any files/subfolders in it?

Comment: First checkout the branch again having the directory. Then you will have the directory in your local. You can then `git rm -r test_directory`

Comment: @ashutosh the only branch I have is master. when i do git co master it tells me I am already on master and it is up to date with origin/master

Comment: @TheHurricane okay, let us know what is the output of `git status` and add the same in question post.

Comment: How about using `git commit -a`? it will automatically notice and record all removals.

Comment: anyone interested, posted my solution below :)

Comment: I think that `git checkout -- test_directory`, after that `git rm -r --cached test_directory` is able to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Ok so found a solution. I git stashed, then git commit -am "WIP" then git pushed.